# Bulk delete messages on discord.net 2.x

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

```
    [Command("purge")]
    [Summary("Deletes the specified amount of messages.")]
    [RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.Administrator)]
    [RequireBotPermission(ChannelPermission.ManageMessages)]
    public async Task PurgeChat(int amount)
    {
        var messages = Context.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(amount + 1).Flatten();
        await ((ITextChannel)Context.Channel).DeleteMessagesAsync(messages);
    }
```

I want to delete last `amount` messages and came up with this code. But apparently I get an error saying

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

I am using `Discord.net 2.x`.
How can I fix the error and why did it happen?

Comment: What type of "messages"?

Comment: Normal text messages. @galakt

Comment: I ask type, not what does it mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took some help from the Discord-api unofficial server and they told me that I have to `await` the method and also use `FlattenAsync()` and not `Flatten()` in discord.net 2.x.

So I summed up to

```
IEnumerable<IMessage> messages = await Context.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(amount + 1).FlattenAsync();
await ((ITextChannel) Context.Channel).DeleteMessagesAsync(messages);
const int delay = 3000;
IUserMessage m = await ReplyAsync($"I have deleted {amount} messages for ya. :)");
await Task.Delay(delay);
await m.DeleteAsync();
```

and this is working perfect.

Comment: I got a question to this code snippet. It is working fine but as soon as I want to delete 4 messages at once it is not doing anything. No Crash no error messages nothing. Code gets executed and the method is called

Comment: I got an instant answer to that. The Bulk_Delete of message is only working for like the last 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `await` keyword,

```
var messages = (await Context.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(amount + 1)).Flatten();
```

If you need these to execute in parallel to another task in this method (which I doubt so), you can use [`ContinueWith()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) method instead.

Comment: Using this gave me an error `'IAsyncEnumerable<IReadOnlyCollection<IMessage>>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncEnumerable<IReadOnlyCollection<IMessage>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `